# Apache solr search text search (among multiple fields)

Tags: solr

I am studying/getting familiar Apache Solr database.

I created a simple document via the admin UI:

```
 {
        "company_name":["Rikotech inc"],
        "id":"12345",
        "full_title":["ft rikotech marinov"],
        "_version_":1681062832169287680}]
  }
```

Here is the document fetched:
[image]

But when I type `rikotech` in the standard query field, I get no result:
[image]

Both `full_title` and `company_name` are of type **text_general** .

I watched YouTube video with some Indian guy, and it worked for him ;|

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Solr will not search all fields (under any configuration, really) without specifying the fields. However, the tutorial you watched probably had the default `copyField` rule enabled where everything is copied into a field named `_text_`, and then that field is configured as the default search field. This effectively means that everything is being copied into a specific field, and then that (single) field is being searched by default.

In your case it's probably better to use the `edismax` query parser (check the box in front  of `edismax` in the user interface), and then give `full_title company_name` as the query fields (`qf`). That will allow you to adjust the weights between the fields as well. `full_title company_name^5` will give 5x as much weight to any hits in `company_name` compared to those in `full_title`.

Comment: @MatsLindth the problem in my occasion was quite the opposite - the search fields were NOT coppied to the _text_ field by default but to some other fields (i dont know where they came from). For example company_name was coppied to company_name_str. Changing the copy to _text_ solved my problem

Comment: I would have added this information to my original post ,but I didnt know what this copy even means and what is it used for. I am total beginner

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

It was that the fields I want to search through by default were copied to some strange fields like full_title_str, instad of *text* . This is the correct schema setting:

[image]